# Unexpected token '<', \"\r\n<script i\"... is not valid JSON"

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework

Buen dia, hago esta publicacion por que ya he tratado de todo y no se cual es el error:

Estoy programando en ionic angular, tengo el html con botones que se adjuntar un archivo pdf y luego con el boton enviar al final se envian estos archivos. El array se muestra correctamente con los files pero al enviar al sevidor php sale el error del titulo.

**este es mi html:**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar class="header">
    <ion-title class="texto-header">Documentación</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="start" style="color:#ffffff;">
      <ion-menu-button menu="main-menu"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Certificado de Acreditación</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      Aqui deberas adjuntar el certificado que acredita tu especialidad y el ejercer la profesión.
      <p>*El archivo debe ser en formato pdf*</p>
    </ion-card-content>
    <ion-button (click)="onFileInput(1)" class="custom-button">Adjuntar Archivo
      <input type="file" (change)="onFileInputChange($event, 1)" accept=".pdf" style="display: none" #fileInput1>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Certificado de Antecedentes</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      Aqui deberas adjuntar el certificado de antecedentes otorgado por SRCEI.
      <p>*El archivo debe ser en formato pdf*</p>
    </ion-card-content>
    <ion-button (click)="onFileInput(2)" class="custom-button">Adjuntar Archivo
      <input type="file" (change)="onFileInputChange($event, 2)" accept=".pdf" style="display: none" #fileInput2>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Titulo o diplomado</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      Aqui deberas adjuntar tu titulo o diplomado correspondiente.
      <p>*El archivo debe ser en formato pdf*</p>
    </ion-card-content>
    <ion-button (click)="onFileInput(3)" class="custom-button">Adjuntar Archivo
      <input type="file" (change)="onFileInputChange($event, 3)" accept=".pdf" style="display: none" #fileInput3>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Otro Archivo</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      Aqui podras adjuntar cualquier otro archivo.
      <p>*El archivo debe ser en formato pdf*</p>
    </ion-card-content>
    <ion-button (click)="onFileInput(4)" class="custom-button">Adjuntar Archivo
      <input type="file" (change)="onFileInputChange($event, 4)" accept=".pdf" style="display: none" #fileInput4>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-card>

  <!-- Botón para enviar los archivos -->
  <ion-button (click)="enviarArchivos()" class="custom-button" expand="block">Enviar Archivos</ion-button>
</ion-content> <ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar class="header">
    <ion-title class="texto-header">Documentación</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="start" style="color:#ffffff;">
      <ion-menu-button menu="main-menu"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Certificado de Acreditación</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      Aqui deberas adjuntar el certificado que acredita tu especialidad y el ejercer la profesión.
      <p>*El archivo debe ser en formato pdf*</p>
    </ion-card-content>
    <ion-button (click)="onFileInput(1)" class="custom-button">Adjuntar Archivo
      <input type="file" (change)="onFileInputChange($event, 1)" accept=".pdf" style="display: none" #fileInput1>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Certificado de Antecedentes</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      Aqui deberas adjuntar el certificado de antecedentes otorgado por SRCEI.
      <p>*El archivo debe ser en formato pdf*</p>
    </ion-card-content>
    <ion-button (click)="onFileInput(2)" class="custom-button">Adjuntar Archivo
      <input type="file" (change)="onFileInputChange($event, 2)" accept=".pdf" style="display: none" #fileInput2>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Titulo o diplomado</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      Aqui deberas adjuntar tu titulo o diplomado correspondiente.
      <p>*El archivo debe ser en formato pdf*</p>
    </ion-card-content>
    <ion-button (click)="onFileInput(3)" class="custom-button">Adjuntar Archivo
      <input type="file" (change)="onFileInputChange($event, 3)" accept=".pdf" style="display: none" #fileInput3>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Otro Archivo</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      Aqui podras adjuntar cualquier otro archivo.
      <p>*El archivo debe ser en formato pdf*</p>
    </ion-card-content>
    <ion-button (click)="onFileInput(4)" class="custom-button">Adjuntar Archivo
      <input type="file" (change)="onFileInputChange($event, 4)" accept=".pdf" style="display: none" #fileInput4>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-card>

  <!-- Botón para enviar los archivos -->
  <ion-button (click)="enviarArchivos()" class="custom-button" expand="block">Enviar Archivos</ion-button>
</ion-content> <ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar class="header">
    <ion-title class="texto-header">Documentación</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="start" style="color:#ffffff;">
      <ion-menu-button menu="main-menu"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Certificado de Acreditación</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      Aqui deberas adjuntar el certificado que acredita tu especialidad y el ejercer la profesión.
      <p>*El archivo debe ser en formato pdf*</p>
    </ion-card-content>
    <ion-button (click)="onFileInput(1)" class="custom-button">Adjuntar Archivo
      <input type="file" (change)="onFileInputChange($event, 1)" accept=".pdf" style="display: none" #fileInput1>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Certificado de Antecedentes</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      Aqui deberas adjuntar el certificado de antecedentes otorgado por SRCEI.
      <p>*El archivo debe ser en formato pdf*</p>
    </ion-card-content>
    <ion-button (click)="onFileInput(2)" class="custom-button">Adjuntar Archivo
      <input type="file" (change)="onFileInputChange($event, 2)" accept=".pdf" style="display: none" #fileInput2>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Titulo o diplomado</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      Aqui deberas adjuntar tu titulo o diplomado correspondiente.
      <p>*El archivo debe ser en formato pdf*</p>
    </ion-card-content>
    <ion-button (click)="onFileInput(3)" class="custom-button">Adjuntar Archivo
      <input type="file" (change)="onFileInputChange($event, 3)" accept=".pdf" style="display: none" #fileInput3>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Otro Archivo</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      Aqui podras adjuntar cualquier otro archivo.
      <p>*El archivo debe ser en formato pdf*</p>
    </ion-card-content>
    <ion-button (click)="onFileInput(4)" class="custom-button">Adjuntar Archivo
      <input type="file" (change)="onFileInputChange($event, 4)" accept=".pdf" style="display: none" #fileInput4>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-card>

  <!-- Botón para enviar los archivos -->
  <ion-button (click)="enviarArchivos()" class="custom-button" expand="block">Enviar Archivos</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

**este es el typescript:**

````
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DocumentacionService } from './service/documentacion.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-documentacion',
  templateUrl: './documentacion.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./documentacion.page.scss'],
})
export class DocumentacionPage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('fileInput1') fileInput1!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('fileInput2') fileInput2!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('fileInput3') fileInput3!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('fileInput4') fileInput4!: ElementRef;

  filesToUpload: File[] = []; // Almacena los archivos seleccionados

  constructor(private dcService: DocumentacionService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onFileInput(buttonNumber: number) {
    if (buttonNumber === 1) {
      this.fileInput1.nativeElement.click();
    }
    if (buttonNumber === 2) {
      this.fileInput2.nativeElement.click();
    }
    if (buttonNumber === 3) {
      this.fileInput3.nativeElement.click();
    }
    if (buttonNumber === 4) {
      this.fileInput4.nativeElement.click();
    }
  }

  onFileInputChange(event: any, buttonNumber: number) {
    const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        const selectedFile: File = fileList[i];
        if (selectedFile.type === 'application/pdf') {
          this.filesToUpload.push(selectedFile);
          console.log(this.filesToUpload);
        } else {
          alert('Por favor, selecciona solo archivos en formato PDF.');
          this.clearInput(buttonNumber);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  clearInput(buttonNumber: number) {
    if (buttonNumber === 1) {
      this.fileInput1.nativeElement.value = null;
    }
    if (buttonNumber === 2) {
      this.fileInput2.nativeElement.value = null;
    }
    if (buttonNumber === 3) {
      this.fileInput3.nativeElement.value = null;
    }
    if (buttonNumber === 4) {
      this.fileInput4.nativeElement.value = null;
    }
  }

  enviarArchivos(): void {
    const formData = new FormData();
  
    for (let i = 0; i < this.filesToUpload.length; i++) {
      formData.append(`file${i + 1}`, this.filesToUpload[i]);
    }
    console.log(formData)
    this.dcService.enviarArchivos(formData).subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        console.log('Archivos enviados con éxito:', response);
        console.log(formData)
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error al enviar archivos:', error);
        // Manejar el error aquí
      }
    );
  }
} ```
````

**este es el service para enviar al backend los archivos**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DocumentacionService {

  private url = "http://localhost/sense/ws"; 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  enviarArchivos(formData: FormData): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.url}?m=documentacion&f=recibirDocumentos`;
    return this.http.post(url, formData);
  }  
}
```

**y este es el codigo de php la funcion para obtener estos archivos**:

```
public function recibirDocumentos() {
        $id_usuario = 25; // Obtener el ID del usuario desde la solicitud
    
        // Directorio donde se guardarán los archivos
        $carpeta_destino = 'assets/documentos/' . $id_usuario . '/';
    
        if (!is_dir($carpeta_destino)) {
            mkdir($carpeta_destino, 0777, true); // Crea el directorio si no existe
        }
    
        $success = true;
        $message = '';
        
        foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
            if (is_array($file['name'])) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($file['name']); $i++) {
                    if ($file['error'][$i] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                        $nombre_archivo = $file['name'][$i];
                        $ruta_temporal = $file['tmp_name'][$i];
                        $nombre_final = $carpeta_destino . $nombre_archivo;
    
                        if (!move_uploaded_file($ruta_temporal, $nombre_final)) {
                            $success = false;
                            $message = 'Error al mover los archivos';
                            break; // Detiene el proceso si hay un error
                        }
                    } else {
                        $success = false;
                        $message = 'Error al subir los archivos';
                    }
                }
            } else {
               
                if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                    $nombre_archivo = $file['name'];
                    $ruta_temporal = $file['tmp_name'];
                    $nombre_final = $carpeta_destino . $nombre_archivo;
    
                    if (!move_uploaded_file($ruta_temporal, $nombre_final)) {
                        $success = false;
                        $message = 'Error al mover el archivo';
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    $success = false;
                    $message = 'Error al subir el archivo';
                }
            }
        }
    
        $response = json_encode(array(
            'success' => $success,
        ));
    
        echo $response;
        exit();
    }
```

Finalmente creo que el formdata que se envia al servidor no esta almacenando estos files dentro del arreglo, y en consola me esta saliendo el error:

error
:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', " <script i"... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:78725:41) at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:8319:171) at http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:90422:49 at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:90422:30) at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:8319:54) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:90736:25) at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:8319:54) at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:8120:37) at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:8396:26)
message
:
"Unexpected token '<', "\r\n<script  i"... is not valid JSON"
stack
:
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "\r\n<script  i"... is not valid JSON\n    at JSON.parse ()\n    at XMLHttpRequest.on

Entonces la idea es tener 4 botones en el html donde se adjunten 4 archivos pdf, luego con el botón enviar enviar estos archivos al backend y almacenarlos en la carpeta assets/documentacion( en principio estoy asignando la id=25 ya que después traeré el id de la app para sumarla a la función del backend.
ya no se que será por favor su ayuda :(

Comment: Debería tener un JSON pero tienes otra cosa. Te recomiendo comenzar comprobando si es PHP funciona correctamente, para eso puedes usar POSTMAN

Comment: en postman y en red me sale lo mismo: status 200 (ok) pero en respuesta sale esto:

<script id="debugbar_loader" data-time="1698954461.900750" src="http://localhost/sense/?debugbar"></script>
<script id="debugbar_dynamic_script"></script>
<style id="debugbar_dynamic_style"></style>
<script class="kint-rich-script">

y mucho mas código hacia abajo claro, pero dejo eso como ejemplo.

Comment: El código 200 es porque el servidor pudo procesar correctamente tu solicitud, es decir encontró la ruta y la ruta arrojó una respuesta. Tu problema es que la respuesta no es valida, el servidor te está devolviendo un HTML cuando tu esperas un JSON.  Esto en PHP sucede frecuentemente cuando tu código da una *Exception*, es decir hay un error en tu código. Es muy común que en estos caso PHP retorne código HTML con el mensaje de error y warnings

Comment: Saludos. Revise lo siguiente; el servidor devuelve el Status 200; que concluyo la petición exitosa (no necesariamente la que solicito, sino que el servidor respondió), por el `<script...` que mencionas llega en respuesta (en este caso en **POSTMAN**) mira más; puede ser un HTML que incluya detalles de una respuesta o que página "te está respondiendo" puede encuentres alli que responde ocurrió un error o esta respondiendo una página no llamada o no existentes. **Actualmente no estás recibiendo un JSON de respuesta eso es claro.**